# str_replace. replacing numbers from a string

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

HI all I have this code here

```
$pathinfo = pathinfo($fullpath);
$tags = $shortpath;
$tags = str_replace("/", " ", $tags);
$tags = str_replace("__", " ", $tags);
$tags = str_replace(".png", "", $tags);
$tags = str_replace(".jpg", "", $tags);
$tags = str_replace(".jpeg", "", $tags);
$tags = str_replace(".gif", "", $tags);
```

Everything works fine with the above but I also need it to replace some numbers at the start of the files I am adding

example of a file would be

247991 - my_small_house.jpg

its the numbers before the "-" I need gone
Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex with preg_replace() or preg_split(), but I think explode() would be better:

```
$chunks = explode('-',$shortpath);  // you just keep the part after the dash
$tags = str_replace(array('/','__'),' ', $chunks[1]);
$tags = str_replace(array('.png','.jpg','.jpeg','.gif'),'',$tags);
/* used array to avoid code repetition */
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the number you have to delete made of a fixed number of digits?
If so, you could just do:

```
$tags = substr($tags, 9);
```

Else, if you're sure that every number ends with " - ", you could do:

```
$tags = substr($tags, strrpos($tags," - ") + 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/^[0-9]+(.+)/', '$1', $tags);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks sadly that didn't work as it still is adding the numbers.